# First object from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` with card objects which have values 1 - 15. I shuffle these cards and then I want to share the cards among players. The problem I am having is that I want the first card to be shared/ drawn should always be 3. After the first draw, the sharing should be random (after the first card draw the last card of the deck). For example card.value = 3, 9, 6, 2, 1. Second sharing 3, 4, 13, 9, 2. Etc.

```
-(void) drawCard {
if([self isPlayerAllowedToDrawCard]) {
//First card should be card.value 3... Then
    Card *card = [[Game game].deckCards lastObject];
    [[Game game].deckCards removeLastObject];
    [_playerCards addObject:card];
```

Comment: Shuffle without the 3 card. Create the 3 card and use `insertObject:atIndex:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the 3 card, do your shuffling, then place it at index 0.